# 過去の天気情報を取得できる無料のAPIを探しています

Tags: c#, api

位置情報と日付を投げると過去の天気情報を取得できるAPIを探しています。
Unityで開発しているためC#で書かれてある参考サイトなどが嬉しいです。

よろしくお願いします

Comment: C# から呼び出せる天気APIが複数あった場合、どういうものの方がより「良い」ですか？　判断基準を具体的に頂くことは可能でしょうか。

Comment: 2行目は「APIを用いたC#のプログラムを書く際の参考サイト」を求めているので、別質問に分けた方がよい気がします。

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/ には daily グラフがあるので使えるかもしれません。

Comment: openweathermapは過去のデータは取れるようですが無料のフリーアカウントでは取得できないはずです。[こちら](https://openweathermap.org/price#history)に料金表があります。またプランによって取得できる過去の期間にも差があります。

Answer (score 1):

APIではないですが、国土交通省・気象庁のこのページでデータの検索やダウンロードが出来るようです。

ホーム > 各種データ・資料 > 過去の気象データ検索
http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/index.php
ホーム > 各種データ・資料 > 過去の気象データ・ダウンロード
http://www.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/risk/obsdl/index.php

ホーム > 案内・申請 > 情報ご利用ガイド
http://www.jma.go.jp/jma/kishou/usage_info/guide_top.html

なお、迅速に答えが欲しいならば、何人にもコメントされているように、
質問の背景とか、やりたいこと・欲しいものの細かい条件とかも記述しておく方が良いでしょう。
また、検索は誰でも簡単に出来るので、自分で行った検索結果を示して、
どれが近いとか、これは条件が合わないとかの情報も付加すると良いと思います。

例えば検索すればこんなのが直ぐに出てきます。

商用利用可能な気象データ・天気APIの入手先一覧まとめ
http://sounansa.net/archives/1326

Webサイト制作やアプリ開発で使える天気予報APIのまとめ
http://hello-apis.blogspot.jp/2013/03/webapi.html

ただし、どちらのサイトにもあるように、「商用利用＝有料」ですし、
商用ではなくても、作ったサービスを公開して広く使えるようにしたり、
個人でも高頻度に使用して、提供元の業務に支障が出るようだと、最悪は
逮捕・起訴などが考えられます。

しばらく前に図書館の購入書籍案内に個人利用だが1分毎にアクセスに
行って、システム自身の作りの弱さも手伝ってサービスをダウンさせて
逮捕などされてた件が有名だと思います。

十分に注意してください。

Comment: 補足: [岡崎市立中央図書館事件](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B2%A1%E5%B4%8E%E5%B8%82%E7%AB%8B%E4%B8%AD%E5%A4%AE%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)は結局起訴猶予処分になりましたが、リンクした Wikipedia 記事にも書かれているように、専門家の間でも多少議論になっています。

Comment: うろ覚えで1分毎にアクセスと書きましたがリンク先を見ると1秒毎だったようですね。